# Font is not change but modified git when using gulp-iconfont

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, gulp

Font not change.

However `git status` was modified.

When font changed to git recognized.

**assets path**

```
$ tree app/assets/
app/assets/
├── fonts
│   ├── app
│   │   └── assets
│   │       └── scss
│   │           └── utility
│   │               └── _iconfonts.scss
│   ├── iconfonts.eot
│   ├── iconfonts.svg
│   ├── iconfonts.ttf
│   ├── iconfonts.woff
│   └── iconfonts.woff2
├── iconfonts
│   ├── a.svg
│   ├── b.svg
└── scss
    ├── _iconfontsTemplate.scss
    └── utility
```

**gulpfile.js**

```
const gulp        = require('gulp');
const svgmin      = require('gulp-svgmin');
const iconfontCss = require('gulp-iconfont-css');
const iconfont    = require('gulp-iconfont');
const src = './app/assets';

gulp.task('iconfonts', ['create-iconfonts'], () => {
  gulp.src(`${src}/fonts/*`)
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
});

gulp.task('create-iconfonts', (callback) => {
  gulp.src(`${src}/iconfonts/*.svg`)
    .pipe(svgmin())
    .pipe(iconfontCss({
      fontName: 'iconfonts',
      path: `${src}/scss/_iconfontsTemplate.scss`,
      targetPath: `${src}/scss/utility/_iconfonts.scss`,
      fontPath: `${src}/fonts`
    }))
    .pipe(iconfont({
      fontName: 'iconfonts',
      formats: ['ttf', 'eot', 'woff', 'woff2', 'svg'],
      appendCodepoints: false
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(`${src}/fonts`))
    .on('end', () => { callback() });
});
```

**git status at present**

```
$ git status
On branch test/hoge
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

So far, so good.

Font not change.

**But, following command was modified to git.**

```
$ ./node_modules/.bin/gulp create-iconfonts
```

**Git modified as follows.**

```
$ git status
On branch test/hoge
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   app/assets/fonts/iconfonts.eot
        modified:   app/assets/fonts/iconfonts.ttf
        modified:   app/assets/fonts/iconfonts.woff
        modified:   app/assets/fonts/iconfonts.woff2

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Do you have any good idea?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by **When font changed to git recognized**. Did you do any changes to the fonts? If not, are those changes (to the font files) kind of related to the current time and date e.g. is the creation date included in those files? Would it be an option to remove the generated files from git?

Comment: Thank you for replying.
I'm sorry I'm late.
It's difficult for me to express my mind in English.

I would like to run gulp ( `$ gulp create-iconfonts` ) when changing font file.
The changing font file is `create` ( `$ touch app/iconfonts/c.svg` ) and `rename` ( `$ mv app/iconfonts/a.svg -> app/iconfonts/d.svg` ) and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem here. The cause was the `timestamp` property. Git will assume the file was modified because of it.

I set the timestamp to a constant number like `1661981543` (result of `Math.round(Date.now()/1000)`) and git will only assume  the file was modified if the font is really changed.

```js
iconfont({
 timestamp: 1661981543, // same timestamp always so git doesn't assume the file was modified
})
```

If you have some task to clean the fonts before build, you should consider removing it too.